# Detect when mapItemForCurrentLocation fails to locate your device

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapitem

I can't figure out how to test for a lack of success when getting the map's current location.

```
let source = MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation()
// returns an object with:
//   isCurrentLocation = 1
//   name="Unknown location"
```

I could test `source.name == "Unknown location"` but that would be *terrible* and **bad**.

So... how do I detect failure/nil in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

...
```

Delegates

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

        if (!locations.isEmpty)
        {

            let myLocation  = locations[0] as! CLLocation

            mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(myLocation.coordinate.latitude, myLocation.coordinate.longitude),
                MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.06, 0.06)), animated: true)
        }

    }
```

Comment: I use CLLocationManaager's `didUpdateLocations` in other places.. I even store the most recent location in an external property (like `myLocation` here). I don't love it. It comes out of sync with reality. Say there's an error next time. Then your state says you have a location but you don't really. Then you catch the error and write your state var to nil. Works, but are you missing a different case? External state sucks for this.